# CSS3 Javascript trigger transition animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a DIV class setup as follows:

```
div.map_view{
height: 420px;
transition: height 2s;
-moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

The purpose is when I change the height of this DIV, it animates a scroll (up in this case).  When I call this function in my script:
`document.getElementById('map_view').style.height = '0px';`, it just immediately disappears (doesn't animate).  However, if I comment this out and call the exact same line in my JS debugger, the animation works.

Why is this?  What am I missing that causes it to do nothing in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a helpful tutorial here: [CSS3 Transitions in JavaScript](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/).  I basically setup my two CSS3 class definitions and use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` function to change between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I know I've cut a couple of corners with this by using jquery but here's what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6J4/7/

Take a look at that.